# Efeito cortina invertido CSS

Tags: html, css

Boas

Basicamente eu quero fazer o efeito de cortina ao contrario, vou deixar mais claro nos prints!

Quando a pessoa passa ( on hover ) eu queria q tivesse uma cortina mais escura e que subisse, ou seja estaria a tapar.

[image: img1]

[image: hover]

De momento tenho o codigo assim:

```
.card {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
}

.card::before {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transform-origin: top center;
    transform: scale3d(1, 0, 1);
    transition: 1s;
}

.card:hover::before {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    visibility: visible;
}
```

exemplo do que quero só que ao contrario: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50979913/simple-curtain-effect-on-hover-using-pure-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É só trocar o `top` por `bottom` em `transform-origin` para que o efeito seja de *baixo pra cima* em vez de *cima pra baixo* e acrescentar a propriedade `background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);` no `hover` do `::before` para que o fundo fique totalmente opaco após a animação.

Veja:

```css
.card {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
width: 100px;;
height: 150px;
background: red;
}

.card::before {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transform-origin: bottom center;
    transform: scale3d(1, 0, 1);
    transition: 1s;
}

.card:hover::before {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    visibility: visible;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
   Card
</div>
```

Mas também há outra forma um pouquinho mais simples aumentando o `height` do elemento `::before`:

```css
.card {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
width: 100px;;
height: 150px;
background: red;
}

.card::before {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 1s;
}

.card:hover::before {
    opacity: 1;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
   Card
</div>
```

Comment: valeu pela a ajuda mas ainda nao é bem isso, eu queria que o  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); já tivesse aparecendo e depois é q subia para mostrar a imagem :S

Comment: Então seriam duas camadas?

Comment: imagine, div card dps uma img, aí no efeito eu queria que no site tivesse ja aparecendo o overlay (cortina mais escura que a imagem) e que depois quando desse hover ela subisse, nao sei se me tou explicar bem rsrs

Comment: Veja se é isso: https://jsfiddle.net/vhyk5bc9/

Comment: aiii valeuuu, é isso mesmo obrigado cara <33